# Trying to pass view implicitly using mvc:view controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring configuration file with **MANY** entries such as the one below.

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/test/one" view-name="one.xml" />
<mvc:view-controller path="/test/two" view-name="two.xml" />
<mvc:view-controller path="/test/three" view-name="three.xml" />
```

Now I am integrating controller code and I am trying to avoid having to have a request mapping for every single page. Is there a way for Spring MVC to implicitly find the page with the view as specified in the controllers.xml.

So instead of returning a string as the View. I would like a method where I was returning void or just the model to the page and for it to find the page

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/one", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getOne(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

    // Business Logic
    return "one.xml" // would like to be able to return void here or just the mode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea of `mvc:view-controller` is precisely to avoid having to implement a controller whan its only job would be to dispatch to a view. Just having this tag in the XML is sufficient. You don't need a controller.

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-view-controller

If you have controller logic and thus need a controller, then the mvc:view-controller element should be removed, and be replaced by the actual controller, which dispatches to the appropriate view. You may avoid specifying a view name explicitely here using a RequestToViewNameTranslator, as explained [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-coc-r2vnt).

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't explain. Now logic is required in the controller class and I am forced to explicitly specify the view name in the return statement.

Comment: I don't see any problem in specifying the view name in the controller : that's one of its principal missions: choose an appropriate view. If you really don't want to, see my edit.